# How to write an r chunk to load the tidyverse?

Tags: r

Create an R chunk below, where you load the `tidyverse` library.[ This is an assignment question. Im having trouble as to what I shoudl do?]
Do I just write the command to load the library? Or is there a separate r chunk that needs to be written?

Comment: can you provide more detail? In what context do you want to create a chunk? r markdown?

Comment: yes. its on r markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using R Markdown, it is similar to the other answer but if you're talking about chunks then it should be :

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)

```
````

Calling the packages in the `R Setup` chunk is generally what you want to do while producing an R Markdown document.

Here is a full example with the R Markdown "new" document template.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 1):

just

```
library(tidyverse)
```

or what do you mean?